# Application sharing

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I Have a windows application made using VB.net and Mysql database. I want to install it on a Local network to be used by several users on different windows machines. How best can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at

- [ClickOnce - A new VB.NET 2005
  Deployment Tool](http://visualbasic.about.com/b/2006/01/14/clickonce-a-new-vbnet-2005-deployment-tool.htm)
- [Using ClickOnce Deployment in
  VB.NET](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/clkone01.htm)
- [ClickOnce: Delivering .NET
  Applications Via the Net](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33466)
- [ClickOnce Deployment for Windows
  Forms Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh45kb66.aspx)
- [ClickOnce Deployment in .NET
  Framework 2.0](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/041229.htm)

Comment: +1. Covers "installing" the VB.Net app on the user machines. Albert may also be asking about configuring MySQL server though...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install the application on each computer. But you can have on machine running the MySQL server to which the application will connect. This way all users can access the same data.